# Increase bootstrap dropdown menu width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

wondering if anyone has any tips on how to increase the dropdown width?

I have a row containing two columns with a a bit of javascript that slides the dropdown up and down when selected. The problem I am having is that I can't seem to figure how to increase the dropdown width when selected, ideally the dropdown would match the column size. But what is happening is that the dropdown width is only the same size as the text within the dropdown does anyone have a suggestion on how to increase the dropdown width to match the column size?

```
<div class="row question">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="col-md-6" data-toggle="dropdown">
                First column
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of the dropdown -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="col-md-6" data-toggle="dropdown">
                second column
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                    <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--end of the row question -->

<script>
     // ADD SLIDEDOWN ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
    $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
    });

    // ADD SLIDEUP ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your CSS? Here is a JS Fiddel where you can add it, to show us: http://jsfiddle.net/h53UE/1/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add the following css class

```
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 300px !important;
    height: 400px !important;
}
```

Of course you can use what matches your need.

Comment: Note, the `!important` part is not necessary and should typically be avoided if possible. If it is not working without the `!important`, make sure you are including the bootstrap CSS first and then your own customizations to it.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which specifically applies to bootstrap.  The answer from Rich is the only actual answer to this query. -1

Comment: Using `col-*-12` is wrong as it should only be used after `row` or `form-group. And you may want to use `@media (min-width: 768px) and `also `min-width` instead of `width`. Plus remove `height` as this is much better for responsiveness. See http://bootlint.com

Comment: You can change `min-width` without `!important`

Answer (score 58):

***Update 2018***

You should be able to just set it using CSS like this..

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width:???px;
}
```

This works in both Bootstrap 3 and [Bootstrap 4.0.0 (demo)](https://www.codeply.com/go/fClz4WpC8u).

---

A **no extra CSS** option in **Bootstrap 4** is using the [sizing utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) to change the width. For example, here the **w-100** (width:100%) class is used for the dropdown menu to fill the width of it's parent....

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu w-100">
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Choice1</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Choice2</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Choice3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/pAqaPj59N0

Comment: The OP specifically requested bootstrap help.  Same thing I'm looking for.  Your answer is specific to CSS. -1.

Comment: The purpose is of the dropdown is a contextual menu so the intent is that it would *not* be full-width which is why Bootstrap uses a set min-width. Using `col-*-12` just because it is width:100% is a bad idea and would fail [bootlint](http://www.bootlint.com/). In this case a CSS override is preferred, and aligns with what's recommended in the docs for positioning dropdowns.

Answer (score 32):

You can for example just add a "col-xs-12" class to the `<ul>` which holds the list items:

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-toggle="dropdown">
            First column
            <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-12" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                <li>Insert your menus here</li>
                <li>Insert your menus here</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This worked ok on any screen resolution in my site. The class will match the list width to it's containing div I believe:

[image]

Comment: This is actually the only correct solution. Whoever downvoted it has probably missed the fact that the question was related to bootstrap, not just CSS.

Comment: This is not the intended purpose of `col-xs-12` which is for grid layout and should [always be contained](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) in a `row`.

Answer (score 16):

Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a 
 tag is encountered.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Best solution. Tks.

Answer (score 10):

If you have BS4 another option could be:

```
.dropdown-item { 
  width: max-content !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {

    max-height: max-content;
    max-width: max-content;
}
```

Comment: Please be aware of the usage restrictions for this option: https://caniuse.com/?search=max-content

Answer (score 9):

Usually we have the need to control the width of the dropdown menu; specially that's essential when the dropdown menu holds a form, e.g. login form --- then the dropdown menu and its items should be wide enough for ease of inputing username/email and password.

Besides, when the screen is smaller than 768px or when the window (containing the dropdown menu) is zoomed down to smaller than 768px, Bootstrap 3 responsively scales the dropdown menu to the whole width of the screen/window. We need to keep this reponsive action.

Hence, the following css class could do that:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dropdown-menu {
        width: 300px !important;  /* change the number to whatever that you need */
    }
}
```

(I had used it in my web app.)

Answer (score 6):

Usually the desire is to match the menu width to the width of the dropdown parent. This can be achieved easily like so:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `d-inline-block` class to ur dropdown and `w-100` class to ur dropdown-menu

```
<div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can set:

```
width: fit-content;
```

in order for the dropdown-menu to take space as much as its contents require.